# Why do PostSharp, and MSTest fail to build together in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, mstest, postsharp

I am exploring PostSharp.  I ran in to an early snag I don't understand.  I am hoping for insight.

I have VS 2013 12.0.3051.00 Update 2.  I used NuGet to install PostSharp 3.1.43.0.  I also use Resharper 8.2.1 and I have dotMemory 4.0 installed.

I implemented the first tutorial, at http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/getting-started?utm_source=vsx&utm_medium=app&utm_campaign=Learn.  This behaves as expected.  I do some refactoring.  First, I extract the aspects to a library.

```
namespace AspectImplementations
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using PostSharp.Aspects;

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TraceAttribute" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/getting-started?utm_source=vsx&utm_medium=app&utm_campaign=Learn
        /// </remarks>
        public TraceAttribute(string category)
        {
            Category = category;
        }

        public string Category { get; private set; }

        #region Overrides of OnMethodBoundaryAspect

        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(
                string.Format(
                    "Entering {0}.{1}.",
                    args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name,
                    Category));
        }

        public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(
                string.Format(
                    "Leaving {0}.{1}.",
                    args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name,
                    Category));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I compile the project and run it and get expected behavior.

Next, I factor out the methods attibuted with the aspects to their own library.

```
namespace Conversation
{
    using System;
    using AspectImplementations;

    public class Greetings
    {
        [Trace("Hi")]
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, PostSharp");
        }

        [Trace("Bye")]
        public void SayGoodBye()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Goodbye, PostSharp");
        }
    }
}
```

I compile the code, and ignore the warning that PostSharp isn't needed in HelloPostSharp, anymore, run the app, and it behaves as expected.

Now I want to add some unit tests.  MSTest works for me.  This is where my trouble starts.

```
namespace TestConversation
{
    using Conversation;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class TestGreetings
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCtor()
        {
            Greetings talker = new Greetings();
            Assert.IsNotNull(talker);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSayHelloNotExceptional()
        {
            Greetings talker = new Greetings();
            talker.SayHello();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestSayGoodByeNotExceptional()
        {
            Greetings talker = new Greetings();
            talker.SayGoodBye();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get a dialog that suggests I need to add dependencies to PostSharp.  I hit the OK button and let it add stuff.  I get a build failure.  I put "SkipPostSharp" in the HelloPostSharp project, where Main is.  Still won't build.  My Build output looks like

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: AspectImplementations, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  : message : PostSharp 3.1 [3.1.43.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release] complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings, processed in 899 ms
1>  AspectImplementations -> C:\Users\ssailors.WPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HelloPostSharp\AspectImplementations\bin\Debug\AspectImplementations.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Conversation, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  : message : PostSharp 3.1 [3.1.43.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release] complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings, processed in 1313 ms
2>  Conversation -> C:\Users\ssailors.WPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HelloPostSharp\Conversation\bin\Debug\Conversation.dll
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: HelloPostSharp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestConversation, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My error list is empty.  0 Errors, 0 Warnings, 0 Messages.

Apparently, there is something I am not understanding about how to use unit testing with PostSharp.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand, but I am moving past this.  I shut down my machine, traveled to the downtown office, restarted, brought up this project, and it built fine.  I am guessing that some DLL necessary for things to work had been upgraded by PS, but was stuck in memory, and I needed a boot to get it shook free.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot to get the current assemblies in RAM